# Set rel="nofollow" to all dynamic links with /? in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, nofollow

I would like to set `rel="nofollow"` to all dynamic links with `/?` in WordPress for all types of web pages, category, filters etc. Can you recommend a solution? Maybe with some function.php filter?
Did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the solution to this problem is to use some plugin, for example this one.

**Plugin: External Links - nofollow**

Comment: But I need this for internal links.